# Bulk updates of related models

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Update single...

`$modelA->update(['status_id' => 1])`

Update multiple...

`ModelA::whereIn('id', $data['ids'])->update(['status_id' => 1])`

SO

Updating a model **related** to a single row can work as follows...

`$modelA->relatedModel()->update(['status_id' => 1])`

($modelA instance is supplied via route model binding, and the relatedModel() method/relationship is defined in the "ModelA" model)

BUT

When attempting the following,

`ModelA::whereIn('id', $data['ids'])->relatedModel()->update(['status_id' => 1])`

I get an error

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::relatedModel()

It seems that I am not really understanding what is being returned by

`ModelA::whereIn('id', $data['ids'])`

So what I'm looking for is a method of updating the related models of multiple rows (obviously without a loop of any kind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whereIn()` and many other methods, like `where()`, `has()`, `with()`, etc. returns a `Builder` instance, which lets you chain additional queries. You cannot access `ModelA` instance methods, like `relatedModel()` on a Builder instance.

You will need to call `->get()`, and iterate the results calling `relatedModel()->update()`:

```php
foreach(ModelA::whereIn('id', $data['ids'])->get() as $modelA) {
  $modelA->relatedModel()->update(['status_id' => 1]);
}
```

Alternatively, if you'd like a single-liner without a loop, you will need to query the `ModelB` model (or whatever `relatedModel()` is) directly:

```php
ModelB::whereIn('model_a_id', $data['ids'])->update(['status_id' => 1]);
```

Note: Assumed that `ModelB` has a `model_a_id`. If it doesn't, you can use the `whereHas()` method instead:

```php
ModelB::whereHas('modelA', function ($query) use ($data) {
  return $query->whereIn('model_a.id', $data['ids'];
})->update(['status_id' => 1]);
```

Note: Again, made some assumptions on your table/column names; adjust as required.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. I wanted a way to modify the value of modelB from within the "context" of modelA because I'm iterating a list of modelA objects and have the need to bulk update a property from within modelB associated with each modelA. I have endpoints for bulk updating modelB directly as you suggest, so I am aware I could just do that, and I guess I will have to because an update within a loop seems like a bad idea. Thanks very much for responding.

Comment: Yeah, any kind of database call from within a loop is generally a bad idea (unless limited to a small number of iterations, but still), so being able to perform this as a single `->update()` query is definitely better. If you can eager load the related model, then you could do it as `ModelB::whereIn('id', ModelA::with('relatedModel')->pluck('related_model.id'))->update(['status_id' => 1])` for a total of 2 DB queries, but that's essentially the same as the other 2 example queries in the answer. So whatever is performant and easy to understand/modify, etc is probably your best bet here 